# What causes steel rubbing on wood to leave grey or black marks?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

In my own experience, running or rubbing a high-carbon steel on wood leaves a pencil-like trail. Is this simply carbon rubbing off, or is it a more complex reaction involving tannins in the wood, like [another user suggested](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/122923/43374)? EDIT (thanks Ivan Neretin): Or something else entirely, like iron (or its oxides) rubbing off? And to be more precise: is it [lamellar hematite](http://www.reade.com/products/micaceous-iron-oxide-mio) that rubs off and looks gray, or pure iron or a combination?

Comment: Carbon does not react (nor does it rub off). _Iron_ does.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: well, that's the answer then!

Comment: The reaction with tannins requires moisture and some time.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of wood you are talking about ?  if it's a polished one or one with a brown colour coating it would be simply like rubbing of the color part by scratching

Comment: Not coated with anything, just regular softwood timber.